# Query where redundancy and optimization

Tags: database, t-sql, query-optimization

Actually it's a simple question but I'm lacking of experience and know how about the internal optimization of a database system (in general, but T-SQL in my specific case).

Assumed I have a database with integer data fields (for simplification 1-3):

```
table Data (D1, D2, D3)
```

I have a collection of match criteria:

```
D1 > 3       D2 < 100    D3 all
D1 >= 50     D2 all      D3 > 50
and so on...
```

The naive way to perform a query would be to `AND` every expression of a criteria an `OR` every criteria expression. But obviously an optimized query would be <strike>`D1 >= 50 and D2 < 100 and D3 > 50`</strike> (see edit)

**So here's the question**: Is a database (T-SQL in my case) able to optimize my naive query?

**If not**: Can someone point me to the right direction (i'm sure there must be some algorithm for that case I can't figure it out).

Edit:

Obviously the optimization assumption was wrong :-D

```
D1 >= 50     D2 < 100    D3 all
D1 >= 50     D2 all      D3 > 50
and so on...
```

This one could be optimized from
`D1 >= 50 and D2 < 100 or  D1 >= 50 and D3 > 50`
to
`D1 >= 50 and (D2 < 100 or D3 = 50`)

And somehow I assume, that a database should be that smart (if I think about how complex queries become this must be child's play for the database).

The question should be: How much criteria can it handle (X data fields and Y criterias). But that's something I have to figure out. I'll report when we collect some date here (could take a while).

Comment: how are you getting the 'criteria expressions'?  is this some kind of dynamic sql? are they in another table somewhere?  if they are in a nother table - then you can do a pretty straightforward join.

Comment: @Randy Thank you for your response! We didn't decide that yet. What we have right now is the data table. The criteria is a collection of criteria objects right now (field, comparison type, value). I don't see a chance of building a query in a non dynamic way since the operator is dynamic too.

Comment: i think that is a major decision :) - perhaps consider placing those in a table - then you could query that to generate a runtime dynamic sql statement if the regular join does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since there won't be a real answer I'll respond to my own question to provide feedback on this.
(I'm still happy if someone is willing to contribute to this!)

The original question implied a table which contains data and a collection of criteria which is applied to that. In further analysis I faced the fact that the whole concept behind this idea is so complex that we can't rely on saving this criteria in a separate table (reasons: dynamic API and pure chaos when you try to handle that without a clear programming library).

So it ends up in dynamic SQL (instead of joins, stored procedures, etc). Fortunately I can reduce the queried data by previous restrictions which will reduce a great amount of data which will remain to be queried with the criteria. I don't even see a problem in applying (e.g) 100 criterias with 10 rules each anymore. I still worry about how many of such queries in a short period the database can handle (besides the common workload) without bursting into flames.

Still, a pretty neat requirement for me as developer to "struggle" with. I'll report back if there's more to tell...